# Override HMENU that is included in another template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-4.7

In TYPO3 4.7 I have a template that contains:

```
page.10 < temp.mainTemplate
```

This Template has two includes. The first contains this:

```
temp.mainTemplate = TEMPLATE
temp.mainTemplate {
  subparts.menu_1 < temp.menu_1
}
```

And the second contains the actual HMENU typoscript:

```
temp.menu_1 = HMENU
temp.menu_1 {
  #My Menu
}
```

Without altering either of the includes, how can I make an edit to the HMENU in the main template setup?

I have tried this above the first line without success:

```
temp.mainTemplate.subparts.menu_1 {
 #Modifications to My Menu
}
```

I have tried this below the first line without success:

```
page.10.subparts.menu_1 {
  #Modifications to My Menu
}
```

Comment: TYPO3 4.7 is not supportet anymore. Update to 6.2, then to 7.6

Answer (score 0):

`page.10.subparts.menu_1` is the right key to alter. It needs to be places after `page.10 < temp.mainTemplate` of course.

you can test it by deleting the menu completely with `page.10.subparts.menu_1 >` and it should disappear from the webpage.

There is no way of telling what exactly does not work without seeing more of your TS. May be you have just a typo somewhere

Comment: I finally found the problem was that the `page.10 < temp.mainTemplate` line was also used in a separate template on the page I was testing! So overriding everything I tried...